# change this condition using join in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to use join instead of this query with same condition

```
select (
    (
    select 
        case when sum(A.[Quantity]) is null then 0 else sum(A.[Quantity]) END
    from [tablename1] A 
    where   ((A.[Status]=4) AND (A.[Spcl Order]=1) AND (A.[Finished Date] = aa.FromDate ))
    )

    + 

    (
    select 
        case when sum(A.[Quantity]) is null then 0 else sum(A.[Quantity]) END 
    from [tablename2] A 
    where   ((A.[Item Category Code] = 'STYLES') AND (A.[Prod_ Order No_]='') AND 
            ( A.[Buy-from Vendor No_] in (@vendor)) AND (A.[Quantity]>0)    AND
            (A.[Spcl Order]= 1) AND ( A.[Posting Date] = aa.FromDate))
    )
)
```

Comment: What do you need the join for?

Comment: I need to change the above query using join then only query will be used for cube development in sql server

Comment: queries in dsv cannot take parameters that you have here - @vendor

Comment: @Vendor replaced with 'C00303'. I need to develope cube using sql server so i want to alterate the above query using join with same condition

Comment: What you have here in your query is two selects from two tables. You get two results and summing them. In the end you only have one simple result. So what is the problem here and why you want to bring here join? You want this one result to be in CUBE?